# Interface method cannot change TextView text in android

Tags: android, service, interface

I am running an android service. I wish to change a TextView text when I get expected result from the service. I have implemented an interface method to get a callback to change my textView. Interface abstract method runs well but cannot change the Textview text of my activity.

**I have simplified sample code here**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Asim----", "Start service"); // print this line well
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void testMe() {
        Log.e("Asim----", "Hi");  // print this line well
        mTextView.setText("New Text"); // Chrashes happens here
    }

}
```

**The MyService class here**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //super.onCreate();
        Log.e("test1------", "onCreate"); // print this line well
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("test2------", "onStartCommand"); // print this line well

        MyInterface mi = new MainActivity();
        mi.testMe();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: always try to debug your code, it will tell you that something is getting null in this type of issues.

Answer (score 1):

`mTextView` should be `null` you have to find it in this method

```
 @Override
    public void testMe() {
        Log.e("Asim----", "Hi");  // print this line well
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        mTextView.setText("New Text"); // Chrashes happens here
    }
```

Try it once.

Comment: What is your problem now explore it

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass Activity in your interface as well

```
@Override
    public void testMe(Activity actvity) {
        Log.e("Asim----", "Hi");  // print this line well
        mTextView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        mTextView.setText("New Text"); // Chrashes happens here
    }
```